# AWS S3 object not publicly accessible despite bucket policy allowing public access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS S3 bucket that I've made publicly accessible and added a policy to allow public reading of objects:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cancon/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The bucket is entirely public, and all the static files for my web application stored within it are viewable except for one: https://cancon.s3.amazonaws.com/static/img/star_half.svg

When trying to access this file, I'm getting an Access Denied message:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>EJ8K3ZG143FAHD3X</RequestId>
<HostId>QLVfJC56e0elbw7HbLMZ7J8zrfg1H/CxhP2Qtz/prV5TozEjavkb4ciXZxV8F2oRBENti9V72Q8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

The other files added earlier in the same bucket are correctly displayed, even though the public access box for Object is not checked for them. for example https://cancon.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/static/img/raty_off.svg

When uploading a new file via the AWS S3 web interface, the file inherits the same inaccessible settings, despite my bucket policy.

What might be the problem here and how can I solve it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Was that file possibly uploaded using credentials from a different AWS Account? You might want to try disabling ACLs. See: [Disabling ACLs for all new buckets and enforcing Object Ownership - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ensure-object-ownership.html)

Comment: No, the user is the same. I've checked the ACLs disabled box, but I don't see any changes after that. I will leave this setting as it is the recommended setting. 
After that I tried reloading the file and it worked, although I tried it a few times before and it didn't help. 
Not sure what the reason was, but thanks for the advice!